# Slope field and symbolic solution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math

I'm new in MATLAB and I'm not really sure I'm doing it right.
I have the equation

```
y' +2y +3x^2 + 4x + 5 = 0
```

My task is to plot `slope field` of that equation in range `(0,-1)`. Then I have to solve the equation symbolically with `y0=0`. Then to plot the graphic of the equation.

```
axis([-3 6 -3 6])
hold on;
grid on;

function z=ff(x,y)
z=-2*y+3*x^2-4*x+5;
end

%Slope Field I think its working but in wrong range, not (0, -1)
x=-3:0.5:6;
y=-3:0.5:6;
delta=0.2;
for k = 1:length(x)
 for m = 1:length(y)
    plot(x(k), y(m), 'b.')
    eps = delta/sqrt(1 + ff(x(k), y(m))^2);
    plot([x(k) - eps, x(k) + eps],...
    [y(m) - eps * ff(x(k), y(m)),...
     y(m) + eps * ff(x(k), y(m))],'k')
 end
end

%Symbolic solution of the equation

% y0=0; %this is given 
% p = [3 4 5]; %I'm not sure if x0 is going to be the roots of that polynom
%  x0=roots(p);
% plot(x0,y0,'r*')

y=dsolve('Dy+2*y+3*x^2+4*x+5=0','y(0)=0','x');
x=-10:1/100:10; %
plot(x,eval(y)) %solving the equation for y' and then evaluating it
                %but what should x be?
end
```

The result is some strange graphics, that is what making me think I'm doing it wrong. Any help?

Comment: You have some sign incompatibilities between your original formula (all `+`) and your `ff` function (should be all `-`).

Comment: @LutzL thank you dude, can't figure out how I missed the part I understand the most :D Can you look at the last part too, where `y0` is given `0`, how should I find `x0` and then plot the solution? :)

Comment: I interpret the question that you have to use the symbolic solver [dsolve](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/dsolve.html). It does not show how to plot, but that can be [found](http://www3.nd.edu/~nancy/Math20750/Demos/Section2_2/section2_2.html) on other [sites](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~petersd/246/matlabode.html).

Comment: @LutzL than you again. Last thing I ask you, can you take a look at doing the slope field?

Comment: The code looks sensible, if not overly efficient. There surely exist more vectorized variants. But the region that you have to use is not clear. What does (0,-1) mean in the context of a 2 dimensional domain?

Comment: In range of the point (0,-1). I missed to say "point". Hence I have the equation,  I have a point (0,-1), now I have to draw a slope field, which is still not much clear to me, but that's what is said :D

Comment: The last link also had a picture and a link to code for a slope field. I did not try it out but think that your image should look similar. I would increase the density of the plot.

Comment: @LutzL Can I ask you something for another task? But I can't pm you, neither write another post, so if you can tell me how to contact you? :)